# Android getFileDir vs getDir

Tags: android

What is the basic difference between `getDir` and `getFileDir` in android?

AFAIK both will get the internal storage for the application.My question is when should I use `getFileDir`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getFilesDir%28%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
public File getFilesDir ()
```

> Returns absolute path of directory on the filesystem where files created with `openFileOutput(String, int)` are stored.
>
> The returned path may change over time if the calling app is moved to an adopted storage device, so only relative paths should be persisted.
>   No additional permissions are required for the calling app to read or write files under the returned path.

Where as

```
public File getDir (String name, int mode)
```

> It takes name of the directory to retrieve. This is a directory that is created as part of your application data and operating mode(of type int). Use 0 or MODE_PRIVATE for the default operation, MODE_WORLD_READABLE and MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE to control permissions.
>
> Retrieve, creating if needed, a new directory in which the application can place its own custom data files.
>
> You can use the returned File object to create and access files in this directory. Note that files created through a File object will only be accessible by your own application; you can only set the mode of the entire directory, not of individual files.