# how can i access any folder in android 11

Tags: java, android, file-access

this is how I was accessing folders before Android 11.**

```
File someFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/somefolder);
```

but this method not working(deprecated) in android 11.

getExternalFilesDir () - this method returns the application's folder. Android/data/someApp

permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Is there any way you can suggest?**

Comment: I do not exactly understand what your question is, but maybe the Android 11 Storage Update docs helps you to find an answer:  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Comment: Please see for example this question for more details on scoped storage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189667/write-permissions-not-working-scoped-storage-android-sdk-30-aka-android-11

Comment: example i want to access Telegram folder. how can i do this?

Comment: `hi, this is how I was accessing files before Android 11.` Apart from creating a File object that code does nothing. On no Android version. It does not access folders. It does not access files. It does nothing.

Answer (score -1):

I don't exactly know if it's what you mean but you can try to look for the next:
[Android getFileDir vs getDir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514426/android-getfiledir-vs-getdir)